# Grid cells stick out when viewport width falls below 225px

Tags: html, css

Why does the form element, which is now a grid element, does not contain its cells (grid cells are sticking out) when viewport width is changed around 225px?

Here's my link to the code I'm having trouble with: https://codepen.io/skanda1395/pen/RXNZZO

What changes do I need to make the following piece of code?

```
form {
      display: grid;
      width: 50vw;
      margin: auto;
      grid-template-columns:  1.1fr 1.5fr;
      grid-gap: 17px;
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding: 33px;
     }
```

Comment: Hi, it's because you have set your grid-gap and padding values. The cumulative value then gives your form a minimum width so it can't get smaller than them. But also it's probably worth pointing out you don't need to build forms to work below 320px as this is pretty much the lowest width phones go down to. I hope this helps. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To display properly you can put the tags into divs so the grid will easily work

```
      <div>
          <label for="name" id="name-label">Name:</label>
          <input class="wide" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
      </div>

      <div>
          <label for="email" id="email-label">Email:</label>
          <input class="wide" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
      </div>

      <div>
          <label for="number" id="number-label">Age:</label>
          <input class="wide" id="number" type="number" min="0" max="10" placeholder="Enter your age">
      </div>

      <div>
          <label for="dropdown">What do you do?</label>
          <select class="wide" id="dropdown">
          <option>Student</option>
          <option>Full-time Employee</option>
          <option>Self-employed</option>
          <option>Other</option>
          </select>
     </div>
```

You can too nesting the input inside the label, but to work you have to set the display as 'block' like this **label{display:block;}**

```
    <label for="name" id="name-label">Name:
            <input class="wide" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
    </label>
```